# How to disable select box in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers

How to disabled select box but not the option. Here `<select>` tag disabled and also `<option>` is disabled. But I want to only `<select>` tag disabled.

I try with this code

```
echo $this->Form->input('zone_id', array('label' => __('ZONE'), 'id' => 'zoneId', 'disabled' => 'disabled'));
```

This code give html output like that

```
<select name="data[Category][zone_id]" id="zoneId" disabled="disabled">
   <option value="0" disabled="disabled">--Select Zone--</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Subscription Zone</option>
   <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Market Zone</option>
</select>
```

But I want to get html output like this

```
<select name="data[Category][zone_id]" id="zoneId" disabled="disabled">
   <option value="0">--Select Zone--</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Subscription Zone</option>
   <option value="2">Market Zone</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It could just be me, but afaik the options are children from the parent select element. How could you possibly, at least in this case, access the child elements while the parent is disabled?

Comment: @icecub coz I want to make the options are accessible using jquery on button click event.

Comment: So why don't you just remove the disabled part on the button click event?

Comment: I can remove disabled part on the button click. But options are still disabled. only remove disabled part from `<select>` tag.

Comment: Simply something like: `$("#buttonID").on("click", function() { $("#zoneID").children().prop("disabled", false); });` should do it.

Comment: which version of cakephp are you running? I don't get the 'disabled' option in the `<option>` tag

Comment: I'm using 2.6.3 and only the `<select>` tag is disabled, not the options. Anyway, do you know that you can set the attribute of the options? check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044445/cakephp-select-options-attributes) question. You can set `disabled => 0` in your options array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$items = array('0'=>'--Select Zone--','1'=>'Subscription','2'=>'Market Zone');

echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('zone_id', array(
    'options'=> $items, 
    'label' => __('ZONE'), 
    'id' => 'zoneId', 
    'disabled' => 'disabled',
    'default' => 1 // $items's  key which you want to select
));
```

This code give html output like that

```
<div class="input select">
    <label for="zoneId">ZONE</label>
    <select name="data[zone_id]" id="zoneId" disabled="disabled">
        <option value="0">--Select Zone--</option>
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Subscription</option>
        <option value="2">Market Zone</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Its working for me in **CakePHP 2.6.x**.

Comment: You can use `'disabled' => true`. Cake is smart enough to set the attribute correctly.

Comment: yes, i just give a hard coded example, so your problem is solved or not?